# How to find how many user inputs are the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Determine how many numbers are equal. Print that number (zero, two, or three) along with some descriptive text to inform the user of what is being printed to the screen

This only works sometimes and I know that there must be a more efficient way but I am having trouble thinking of something else since I just started learning python.

```
#Taking the inputs from the user 
x,y,z = input("Enter the three valaues: ").split()

while True:
    if x!= y and x!=z:
      print("there is no equal numbers")
      break
    elif x==y or x==z:
      print("There are two equals numbers")
      break 
    else 
      print("There are three equals numbers")
```

Comment: You mean `.split()`, right?

Comment: Even if you fix the split() issue, this will not check numbers. If i give `a a a`, i will get there are 3 equal numbers. Try to address that as well

Comment: What if y and z are equal. Will it work?

Answer (score 2):

You missed the case where `y == z` but `x != y`.

A more readable implementation would be:

```
if x == y == z:
    print("Three equal numbers")
elif x != y and y != z and x != z:
    print("No equal numbers")
else:
    print("Two equal numbers")
```

Also, your `while` should come before your `input` line so that it asks the user a new set of numbers.

---

Answer (score 2):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to find the count of equal numbers:

```
lst = input("Enter 3 values, delimited by blanks: ").split()
num_equal = len(lst) - len(set(lst))
if num_equal:
    num_equal += 1
print(f'There are {num_equal} equal numbers')
```

Comment: Unless OP is also instructed to use the numbers, I'd say casting to `int` isn't necessary.

Comment: @blorgon, thank you for the suggestion to skip the unnecessary conversion to `int`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with 3 values, a slightly different approach than the other two answers would be to use a `set` and a `dict`:

```py
num_equal = 3 - len({x, y, z})
print({0: "No equal numbers", 1: "Two equal numbers", 2: "All three equal"}[num_equal])
```